# Getting album artwork from an mp3 file?

Tags: php, mp3, id3

I wanted to get album artwork from a mp3 file using PHP..could you please provide me some code or point me out a good library to me...

thanks

Comment: You know that this is called ID3 but you couldn't be bothered to [Google "php id3"](https://www.google.com/search?q=id3+php)?

Comment: I did but honestly couldn't get anything useful

Answer (score 0):

[Peter Mescalchin](http://twitter.com/magnetikonline/) has a [great script](http://magnetikonline.com/fetchalbumart/) for doing just this.  Using the [Amazon Web Service API](http://aws.amazon.com/) it automatically fetches missing album artwork.

Answer (score 0):

the Zend_Media_Id3v2 Class is what you need!

download this:
http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/downloads/list

take the Zend folder from the library folder

and use the Example #5 from here:
http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/wiki/ID3v2